Building a maven project failing with ExceptionInInitializerError
I have cloned an existing project to my aws workspace and imported it on Intellij IDEA. It is a maven project and the code is written in java and kotlin. While I am trying to build the project from the IDE it is failing with ExceptionInInitializerError. More information and logs below.
[mehral@a-24xpsmqux7ot1 bin]$ CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
    2024-10-25 18:19:05,328 [   1666]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.l.VfsLog - VFS Log version differs from the implementation version: log null vs implementation -43
    2024-10-25 18:19:06,209 [   2547]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "VSCode" not found PluginDescriptor(name=Terminal, id=org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/tools/idea-IC-231.8770.65/plugins/terminal, version=231.8770.65, package=null, isBundled=true)
    2024-10-25 18:19:12,452 [   8790]   WARN - #c.j.p.PluginClassPathRuntimeCustomizer - There was more than one class loaded in Projector Plugin classloader - this is likely a bug!
    2024-10-25 18:19:14,488 [  10826]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.ActionStub - ActionGroup should be registered using <group> tag: id="PMDPredefined" class="com.intellij.plugins.bodhi.pmd.actions.PreDefinedMenuGroup"
    2024-10-25 18:19:14,490 [  10828]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.ActionStub - ActionGroup should be registered using <group> tag: id="PMDCustom" class="com.intellij.plugins.bodhi.pmd.actions.PMDCustom"
    Info  | RdCoroutineScope          | 75:DefaultDispatcher-worker-55 | RdCoroutineHost overridden 
    2024-10-25 18:19:20,547 [  16885]   WARN - #o.j.i.maven - doScheduleUpdateProjects: Linear Import is disabled
    2024-10-25 18:19:23,284 [  19622]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 414 ms to grab EDT for ToolWindowHeader$2#update@ToolwindowTitle (com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowHeader$2)
    2024-10-25 18:19:23,293 [  19631]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 412 ms to grab EDT for DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxAction#update@NavBarToolbar (com.android.tools.idea.run.deployment.DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxAction)
    2024-10-25 18:19:35,142 [  31480]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 464 ms to grab EDT for DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxAction#update@NavBarToolbar (com.android.tools.idea.run.deployment.DeviceAndSnapshotComboBoxAction)
    2024-10-25 18:19:42,859 [  39197]   WARN - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - kotlin-data-container is not found
    2024-10-25 18:20:16,056 [  72394]   WARN - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - kotlin-data-container is not found
    2024-10-25 18:20:16,522 [  72860] SEVERE - #o.j.k.i.c.KotlinCompilationStatusListener - <Exception from standalone Kotlin compiler>
    Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.currentVersion(BuildNumber.java:297)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getBuildNumber(PluginManagerCore.java:876)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.lambda$createLoadingResult$16(PluginManagerCore.java:822)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.DescriptorListLoadingContext.getDefaultVersion(DescriptorListLoadingContext.java:145)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.readExternal(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:166)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromJar(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:94)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.registerExtensionPointAndExtensions(PluginManagerCore.java:1325)
        at com.intellij.core.CoreApplicationEnvironment.registerExtensionPointAndExtensions(CoreApplicationEnvironment.java:287)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerApplicationExtensionPointsAndExtensionsFrom(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:622)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createApplicationEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:592)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.getOrCreateApplicationEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:548)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.getOrCreateApplicationEnvironmentForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:529)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:473)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:229)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:155)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:91)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1547)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version number: Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0); plugin name: null
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.parseBuildNumber(BuildNumber.java:189)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.fromString(BuildNumber.java:159)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.fromString(BuildNumber.java:124)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber$Holder.readFile(BuildNumber.java:282)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber$Holder.fromFile(BuildNumber.java:255)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber$Holder.<clinit>(BuildNumber.java:249)
        ... 37 more
    2024-10-25 18:20:16,527 [  72865] SEVERE - #o.j.k.i.c.KotlinCompilationStatusListener - IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1  Build #IC-231.8770.65
    2024-10-25 18:20:16,528 [  72866] SEVERE - #o.j.k.i.c.KotlinCompilationStatusListener - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
    2024-10-25 18:20:16,528 [  72866] SEVERE - #o.j.k.i.c.KotlinCompilationStatusListener - OS: Linux
    2024-10-25 18:20:16,529 [  72867] SEVERE - #o.j.k.i.c.KotlinCompilationStatusListener - Plugin to blame: Kotlin version: 231-1.9.22-release-704-IJ8109.175
    2024-10-25 18:20:28,623 [  84961]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Errors during XML parse:
    2024-10-25 18:20:28,623 [  84961]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
    2024-10-25 18:20:48,792 [ 105130]   WARN - #c.i.o.o.e.ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: language for id: preferences.language.Kotlin.scripting
    2024-10-25 18:23:31,347 [ 267685]   WARN - #c.i.o.o.e.ConfigurableCardPanel - auto-dispose 'Plugins' id=preferences.pluginManager
    2024-10-25 18:23:31,997 [ 268335]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - no accessors for com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.Sdk
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,916 [ 269254]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 1
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,917 [ 269255]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 2
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,917 [ 269255]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 3
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,918 [ 269256]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 4
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,918 [ 269256]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 5
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,918 [ 269256]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 6
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,918 [ 269256]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 7
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,918 [ 269256]   WARN - org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint - Unmatched cancel notification for request id 8
    2024-10-25 18:23:32,944 [ 269282]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.i.j.JrtFileSystemImpl - Cannot load into VFS: /home/mehral/.jdks/corretto-17.0.6/release


Intellij version: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1  Build #IC-231.8770.65
Java version: JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor:
JetBrains s.r.o
Kotlin version: 1.6.20
Kotlin plugin version: 231-1.9.10-release-459-IJ8770.65 (the logs show
a different version of the plugin)

Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.currentVersion(BuildNumber.java:297)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getBuildNumber(PluginManagerCore.java:876)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.lambda$createLoadingResult$16(PluginManagerCore.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.DescriptorListLoadingContext.getDefaultVersion(DescriptorListLoadingContext.java:145)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.readExternal(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:166)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptorFromJar(PluginDescriptorLoader.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.registerExtensionPointAndExtensions(PluginManagerCore.java:1325)
    at com.intellij.core.CoreApplicationEnvironment.registerExtensionPointAndExtensions(CoreApplicationEnvironment.java:287)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerApplicationExtensionPointsAndExtensionsFrom(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:622)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createApplicationEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:592)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.getOrCreateApplicationEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:548)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.getOrCreateApplicationEnvironmentForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:529)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:473)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:229)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1547)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version number: Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0); plugin name: null
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.parseBuildNumber(BuildNumber.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.fromString(BuildNumber.java:159)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber.fromString(BuildNumber.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber$Holder.readFile(BuildNumber.java:282)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber$Holder.fromFile(BuildNumber.java:255)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.BuildNumber$Holder.<clinit>(BuildNumber.java:249)
    ... 37 more

I have tried changing the settings, invalidating caches from IDE, even reinstalling maven and IDE but nothing has worked so far. I have tried with different variations of Java, Kotlin and Maven versions as well but that didn't work out either.
Interestingly, the apache maven 3.8.5 is no longer available as I have removed it but it is still showing up somehow, may be from some cache which I didn't find to delete.
Some of the links that I have referred so far:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html#silent
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-go-back-to-a-previous-version-of-the-intellij-kotlin-plugin/8923/2
How do I resolve this error please "Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"
Where could IntellijIDEA cache maven dependencies?


First I would suggest to upgrade your IntelliJ version to most recent version..
